# View not added to application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am confused. This is my Action:

```
public class ZoppenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final HostnameChecker c = new HostnameChecker();
        c.execute(this);
    }
}
```

And this is my zoppen_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000">
</View>
```

The preview (GraphicalLayout-Tab) has a black background, but if i debug the Application, there is no black background. It looks like the view is never added to the application.

What did i wrong?

Comment: where are you calling `setContentView`?

Comment: @learningbrain Nowhere. Do i have to?

Comment: Since you are extending Activity class, it needs to set its View content so that it can show its UI. You need to call `setContentView` for that. Check the docs here on how to set View in `setContentView` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use **setContentView** in Activity to load the View.So add it into onCreate.

```
public class ZoppenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.zoppen_main);
        final HostnameChecker c = new HostnameChecker();
        c.execute(this);
    }
}
```